# SEO domain setup for network of locations

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, subdomain, local-seo

I am looking for some industry expert weigh-in on best practices to how to best approach the business scenario described below.

Tim runs a business, timsbusinesswebsite.com. Tim's business has between 15 and 30 individual locations in large cities across the United States. Unfortunately, the approach to each individual location's digital marketing has been inconsistent.

1. Some have a unique URL for their location (e.g.
   timsbusinesswebsite.com/new-york-city/)
2. Some have a subdomain (e.g.
   chicago.timsbusinesswebsite.com)
3. Some have a separate domain
   altogether (e.g. timsbusinesswebsiitelosangeles.com)

Which of these three approaches would best build the best foundation for the business in local and national rankings from an SEO standpoint and why?

Answer (score 1):

Are the businesses interrelated to each other? Go for sub-folder instead of sub-domain as Google will consider sub-domain as a separate domain name.
Create a skeleton structure for your website.

If you have a country based separation do like this. 
us.example.com
uk.example.com

But, if you are targeting online local location under 1 parent location. Then go for.

Example.com/location-1
Example.com/location-2
Example.com/location-3
Example.com/location-4

**But, you can do it under one domain name by creating different pages for them. that would give you a lot of SEO benefits.**

Suppose:
Country is 1 
Location is a

**

```
Then the pages will be 
example.com 
example.com/a 
example.com/a/services
example.com/a/service-benefits 
example.com/a/contact-us
```

**

Follow the above pattern. 
Let me know if you need any more help on this.